# Chart.js: bad alignment of label during ajax update

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I use `chart.js` to display live data...

```
var doAjax = function() {

$.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(){
                var currentTime = ++time
                var currentValue = Math.random()*1000;
                liveChart.data.labels.push(currentTime);
                liveChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(currentValue);

                liveChart.update();

            },
            complete: function () {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
        });
};

doAjax();
```

...but at the beginning of the update, the first point is displayed in the center of the chart but its label is in the axes origin. How can I align first point and its label? Here is a jsfiddle to see the problem in action https://jsfiddle.net/uue7am8z/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the chart.js source, I can confirm that this is in fact a chart.js bug.  When a line chart is created with a single label and single point, it incorrectly positions the rendering of the point.

I'm working on a fix for this, but in the mean time an official bug has been reported ([#4037](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4037))